# How do I find the final values in the Array by value, reference, and value-result parameter passing?

Tags: arrays, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

In class we are learning about different ways to pass parameters. The ones we are focussing on are by value, by reference, and by value-result. I am given this code fragment

```
int[] A = new int[2];
A[0] = 0;
A[1] = 2;
f(A[0],A[A[0]]);

void f(int x, int y){
     x = 1;
     y = 3;
}
```

What would the final values of Array A be using the three parameter passing methods and can someone please explain how they came to those values?

Update: I think that, since A[0] = 0 then the resulting array if passed by value would be A[0] = 0 and A[1] = 2 because the function does not change the global values of the Array. Also, I think with the value-result parameter passing it would be A[0] = 1 and A[1] = 3, but I don't know for sure or about the pass by reference.

Answer (score 1):

For primitive types java is going to pass parameter as value. So the value will be copied to the function parameters, and the original array is not going to change.
So the array A is not going to change.

If you pass a object as parameter, Java will copy the pointer to the object(the address of the object) . So if you edit any attributes of the object it will change the original one.

The simple way to pass a primitive value "by reference" is to encapsulate it on a object. In Java an array is an object.

```
public static void increment(int[] array, int amount){
   array[0] = array[0] + amount;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
  int[] myInt = { 1 };
  increment (myInt, 5);
  System.out.println ("Array contents : " + myInt[0]); //is going to print 6
}
```

Comment: So via the value passing the Array wouldn't change, but what about the other two?

Comment: Java always pass parameter by value. It always copy the original value. You cannot pass object by reference in Java. You can "simulate" using a object. If you pass a Java Object to method, java will copy the address of the object. It is going to pass by value the address of the object. That is why if you alter a attribute of the object you are going to alter the original object too. Make some sample. It will be more clear.

Comment: I actually just read that this code isn't specifically java related, so that was my error because reference and value-result passing can't be done in java. I will modify my tags.

Answer (score 1):

A[0] would be 0 and A[1] would be 2 because you never update the array values in the code.

Answer (score 0):

call by value:
It is going to copy the value to the function parameter. Changes to the value is not visible to the caller.

call by reference:
It is going to copy the address of the variable. Change on reference parameter are visible to the caller.

call value-result:
It is a special case of call by reference. The content of a variable is going to be copied to another reference. When the function returns this new refence are copied back to the original one. Change on reference parameter are visible to the caller.